# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'innerHTML'

Tags: c#, html, automation, mshtml

I'm using c# mshtml to get html data from a website.

```
public mshtml.HTMLTableRow tr = default(mshtml.HTMLTableRow);

//do some stuff

tr.cells.item(0).innerHTML
```

it is recognizing "item" as a generic object. This used to work but now it is giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you want, but if you want to donwload the FULL html from a website, you can do it this way:

```
using System.Net;
//...
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

    // Or you can get the file content without saving it:
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
}
```

Then you can work with the string if you want a certain part of the code. Hope it helps!!